# Given two equal records on all columns except one, how do i concatenate that column into just one record?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2017

So i need a query to return all the students that are attending a class to assign them to a Evaluation Grid.

I have this SQL tables (just example data)

**Classes**

| Id | SubjectID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ClassId1 | idSubject1 | Classe com profs |
| ClassId2 | idSubject2 | Class |

**ClassStudents**

| Id | TenantUserID | ClassId | Lesson |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id1382832 | UserId3 | ClassId1 | Lesson1 |
| Id43874322 | UserId3 | ClassId1 | Lesson2 |
| Id343881 | UserId3 | ClassId1 | Lesson3 |
| Id312322 | UserId1 | ClassId2 | Lesson1 |
| Id312312 | UserId2 | ClassId2 | Lesson1 |

**ClassTeachers**

| Id | TenantUserID | ClassId | Lesson |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id138233832 | UserId4 | ClassId1 | Lesson1 |
| Id4387214322 | UserId4 | ClassId1 | Lesson2 |
| Id3438ss81 | UserId4 | ClassId1 | Lesson3 |
| Id32212322 | UserId5 | ClassId2 | Lesson1 |
| Id31233312 | UserId5 | ClassId2 | Lesson1 |

**Persons**

| UserId | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UserId1 | Maria Cristina | Lopes Lages |
| UserId2 | Diogo | Miguel |
| UserId3 | Francisco | Lages |
| UserId4 | Joao | Sousa |
| UserId5 | Maria | Maria Dias |

**Subjects**

| Id | SubjectID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | idSubject1 | Classe com profs |
| Id2 | idSubject2 | Class |

```
Select Distinct CONCAT([Persons].[Name],' ', [Persons].[Surname]) AS [StudentName],[Subjects].[Name] As Subject,[Classes].[Name],CONCAT([PS].[Name],' ', [PS].[Surname]) AS [TeacherName]
From Classes
INNER JOIN [Subjects] ON [Subjects].[Id] = Classes.SubjectId
INNER JOIN [ClassTeachers] ON [ClassTeachers].[ClassId] = Classes.Id
INNER JOIN [Persons] AS PS ON [ClassTeachers].[TenantUserId] = [PS].[Id]
INNER JOIN [ClassStudents] ON [ClassStudents].[ClassId] = Classes.Id
INNER JOIN [Persons] ON [ClassStudents].[TenantUserId] = [Persons].[Id]
```

[image: Result]

How do i get records 2/3 and 4/5 to be in a single line with the TeacherName column showing both names?

Comment: I don't know how many times I have said this.  Don't expect detailed, accurate answers if you don't provide detailed inputs for the problem.  Don't expect the answerer to do all of the work.  Please post SQL to create the source tables and data.  You can even verify it works by using sites like https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: Which database system are you using?  Please add a tag.

Comment: The data you posted and the query you posted can't work together.  Please post actual inputs and actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SQLServer from the screenshot and the square brackets around the identifiers. If it's a modern version (2017+) you can:

```
Select  
  CONCAT([Persons].[Name],' ', [Persons].[Surname]) AS [StudentName],
  [Subjects].[Name] As Subject,
  [Classes].[Name],
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT([PS].[Name],' ', [PS].[Surname]), ',') AS [TeacherName]
From Classes
INNER JOIN [Subjects] ON [Subjects].[Id] = Classes.SubjectId
INNER JOIN [ClassTeachers] ON [ClassTeachers].[ClassId] = Classes.Id
INNER JOIN [Persons] AS PS ON [ClassTeachers].[TenantUserId] = [PS].[Id]
INNER JOIN [ClassStudents] ON [ClassStudents].[ClassId] = Classes.Id
INNER JOIN [Persons] ON [ClassStudents].[TenantUserId] = [Persons].[Id]
GROUP BY
  CONCAT([Persons].[Name],' ', [Persons].[Surname]) AS [StudentName],
  [Subjects].[Name] As Subject,
  [Classes].[Name]
```